# Python basic equation error

Tags: python

When running this code it is giving me this error:

> x = p((1/2) - (2/q)) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
p = 0
q = 0

while (p==0):
    p = int(input("Enter an integer for p: "))
while (q==0):
    q = int(input("Enter an integer for q: "))
x = p((1/2) - (2/q))   
print(x)
```

Comment: hint: the error is here `p((1/2) - (2/q))`

Comment: Why are you trying to call p?

Comment: Try `p*((1/2) - (2/q)) ` or `p+((1/2) - (2/q)) ` : python complains because `p` is an integer, not a function

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is happening. You are trying to use an integer as a callable, right here: `p((1/2) - (2/q))`. You are trying to call `p` as if it is a method. But you are clearly storing an integer per this line `p = int(input("Enter an integer for p: "))
while (q==0):`

Comment: it s an equation which i have to do in a python program but somehow it is not working after inputting the p and q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't use `*`, the multiplication operator:

```
x = p * ((1/2) - (2/q))

------^ here
```

In math equations, the multiplication operator is often left out. E.g. `a(b-2)` means "`a` *times* the quantity `b-2`).

In programming however, you must explicitly include the multiplication operator. E.g. `a*(b-2)`.

In Python (and most other languages), when a token is followed by open/close parenthesis, it implies that a function is being called. This is why you received the `'int' object is not callable` error; because `p` is an `int`, and it looked like you were trying to *call* it.

---

You have another problem in your translation from "equation" to Python. In Python 2, *integer division* is used (when both operands are integers, of course). Which means that this term:

```
x = p * ((1/2) - (2/q))
         ^^^^^
```

is going to equal zero.

In Python 3, this is not the case. Division (with a single `/`) is always floating point.

Since this is probably not desired, you should do one of the following:

- Convert one of the terms to `float`, e.g. `float(1)/2`
- `from __future__ import division` which enables the Python 3 behavior
- Just replace the term with `0.5`

Comment: But there's more... one second.

Comment: It`s ok, in our course we are just using python for maths in software development.

Comment: Please see my edit regarding integer vs. floating-point division. Also, remember to up-vote any answer that helps, and accept the answer that best solves your problem.

Comment: The OP is most likely using Python 3, given the use of `input` and the `print` function, but I guess mentioning the Python 2 stuff may be helpful to other readers. FWIW, in the [SO Python Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) our official policy now is to assume Python 3 unless the OP specifically mentions Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to do something like this:

```
p()
```

but p is variable.